# fetching data from a php page and show it in the react js view

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, api

I have a react js web application. I want to fetch data from the server and I am getting errors like:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.8.110/data.php' from origin 'http://192.168.8.110:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have built my react app using npm and create-react-app.

the PHP file path is:

> /usr/local/www/basic/reactproject/data.php

and the js file that I'm fetching the data is:

> /usr/local/www/basic/reactproject/src/routes/dashboard.js

here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
echo'{"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"}]}'
?>
```

and this is dashboard.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hits: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("../data.php")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => 
      this.setState({ hits: data.data},
        this.props.removeLoading()
      )
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { hits } = this.state;  
    console.log(hits)
    return (
      <ul>
        {hits.map(hit =>
          <li key={hit.id}>
            <span>{hit.email}</span>
            <img src={hit.avatar} alt="images"/>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I'm guessing the content type of the JSON you return with PHP is not correct. Try setting a header and also instead returning a JSON as a string try to `json_encode` an array, so that you can make sure your JSON is valid.

Comment: @techouse thank you for your comment. I've tried an API by the same result and it worked properly. but It is not working like this!

Comment: Well then try and add `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` to the PHP and return the JSON properly.

Comment: @techouse still not working. the API I tried was this:https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3

Comment: why aren't you using a .json file directly instead of echoing through php?

Comment: @hexangel616 the data file is dynamically changing and cannot be a json file.

Comment: OK, what's the raw output of your PHP route?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your errors. `fetch("../data.php")` is a relative URL. It won't create a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is used for accessing web resources on different domains. In order to connect your web application to the server you need to unblock "ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN". You can do this by adding an extension to your chrome browser. The link is given below.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino

OR

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: this is not the correct way every end-user is not going to install this add-in 

solution can only be applied a server side in case CORS